# Laplace transform (Simple factorization)

Tags: laplace-transform, factoring

[image]

The question require me to find the inverse of Laplace transform. In the first line of solution, how does it go from LHS to RHS? Does it simply apply partial fractions?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $s^2 = \dfrac{2s^2}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left((s^2-4)+(s^2+4)\right)$

Comment: I can prove it now. But I dont see how is the logic behind of doing this to solve this question. (please see the update.)